# cakephp: how to retrive data from non assiciated model?

Tags: cakephp-2.3

I have three models are User, Equipment , FaultReport

User Table :

```
   id name 

   1    XXXXX 
   2    YYYYYY
```

Equipment Table

```
 id name    
 1   Acer
 2   Fujitsu
```

Fault Report Table :

```
 id   equipment_id  user_id  comment
   1      1              1       good
   2      1              1     Under repair
   3      3              2     condemned
```

I use equipment model to search equipment detail and equipment fault reports using hasMnay relationship. But How can I get user name( who submitted the fault report ). FaultReport and User model are associated using belongsTo. But Equipment model is not associated with User model. So how can I retrieve users name which is associated with faultreport model when I use Equipment Model to search `[ $this->Equipment->find('all') ]`

Please advise me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to fetch data from deeper associated models is to use [Containable Behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html). Enable it in your AppModel:

```
class AppModel extends Model {
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
}
```

Now before executing a query you can set which associated data to fetch:

```
$this->Equipment->contain(array('FaultReport' => array('User')));
$equipment = $this->Equipment->find('all');
```

This code will allow you to get all the data you need.

This is just a basic example. Read the documentation to see how to fetch only specific fields or include conditions in your queries.